# react native "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'string')"

Tags: react-native

Trying to run on emulator an existing RN project. When the app runs on the android emulator(API 29) first shows the splash screen then shows the error.

**Errors from terminal**

[Info] 03-09 08:46:59.686  4743  4831 E ReactNativeJS: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_react.default.PropTypes.string')

[Info] 03-09 08:46:59.698  4743  4831 E ReactNativeJS: Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)

[Info] 03-09 08:46:59.700  4743  4831 E ReactNativeJS: Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)

**versions**

node: 12.9.0

```
"react": "16.11.0"
"react-native": "0.62.2"
```

[Screenshot of emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxkem.png)

Comment: share your code

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the error is React.PropTypes, according to your error logs. Somewhere in your code trying to use PropTypes from React which is no longer existed since React V15.5 [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html). Or maybe you are using an old library that is based on an older React version.